# Android foreground service that can't be killed?

Tags: android, android-service, long-running-processes

Though it may look odd but I am developing an application that will ran on a one specific device with Android 6.0.1 and I don't care about other devices. The app should accomplish a long (very long) running work without any user's interaction as a service in the foreground. In other words I'm trying to use the device as a small server. I don't have much experience in developing mobile aplication but I found out that Android OS interferes too much in applications life circle. And though application starts and works properly for some time it can be unexpectably killed with vague reasons. 
So the question is how to prohibit Android system to interfere with my application? Is it enough to make the application an administrator of the device? Or may be Android devices can't be used in such cases and it's a waste of time?

Comment: I certainly would not use an Android device as a server unless you have no other option. There are plenty of inexpensive low-power devices that can run Linux that would be more suitable platforms.

Comment: Yes, I know. I concider mobile device "upcycling" idea and struggle to make my application works more or less effectivly. In fact Android uses Linux at its kernel and the device seems rather powerful and is equipped with full set of modules I need for my tasks like camera, GPS and mobile internet. I wonder how I can use linux benefits and avoid Android limitations?